# checking whether an element at a certain position exists (is set) in a STL vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I'm writing an algorithm which takes random strings as input. I need to output the maximum length encountered and also how many words have that particular length. YES, I know I can use a different approach but I was thinking to store each string in a v[it's length] and if there are multiple strings with the same length then I would increment u[same length], then just output those values. How can I check whether v[length] is already set?

Sorry for possible bad English.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned short us;
typedef vector<string> vstr;
typedef vector<us> vus;

int main()
{
    string str;
    vstr v;
    vus u(50, 1);
    us len;

    while (cin >> str && str != "0")
    {
        len = str.length();

        //if there is an element set at v[len] then ++u[len] otherwise v[len] = str;
    }

    //bunch of other code

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> YES, I know I can use a different approach

Honestly, I really believe you'd be better off following a different approach then.

You don't need a vector of lengths at all, nor a map, and neither you need a vector of strings unless you want to display those strings as well (here, I will assume you do need it). Finally, you don't even need to know the maximum length of those strings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;

    std::string::size_type maxLength = 0;
    std::string str;
    while (std::cin >> str)
    {
        auto len = str.length();
        if (len == maxLength)
        {
            words.push_back(str);
        }
        else if (len > maxLength)
        {
            maxLength = len;

            words.clear();
            words.push_back(str);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Max length: " << maxLength << std::endl;
    std::cout << "# of words with max length: " << words.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Words with max length: " << std::endl;
    for (auto const& s : words) { std::cout << s << std::endl; }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This won't work unless you know the maximum length of any possible string beforehand. Let's call this maximum X. Then you can construct a vector of X ints, initialized to 0, and just increment the one you need using the subscript operator.

```
std::vector<int> counts(X, 0); // X ints, initialized to 0
for (const string str : v) {
    int length = str.size();
    try {
        counts.at(length)++;
    } catch (const std::out_of_range& oor) {
        // Your professor lied to you!
    }
}
```

The way I would approach this problem would be to use a `map`. Then you can just do the following:

```
std::map<int, int> counts;
for (const string str : v) {
    int length = str.size();
    ++counts[length];
}
```

counts[length] will create the element at [length] if it doesn't exist already, and will increment it if it already exists.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I do know the maximum length of any possible given string, it's 20. This is actually a simple homework task and it says "random strings of maximum 20 characters". Provided I have this information how would I proceed?

Comment: Aye, I saw it now. can you please explain this line? "for (string str : v)". I don't understand that iteration

Comment: That's a `range-for` loop. It iterates over every element in `v`, and passes each element in `v` into your loop as the identifier `str`.

Answer (score 0):

A `std::vector v` has a length given by `v.size()`, and all elements in the range `[0,v.size())` exist.

So an element exists at `v[n]` if `v.size() > n`

You can test for it either by checking the vector's length, or accessing the element with `v.at(n)` instead of `v[n]` because the `at()` function will throw an exception if the element doesn't exist (that is, if the length is not at least `n`)

The fact a `std::vector` contains an element at every index up to its length means it is not an efficient representation of a [sparse array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array) To represent a sparse array with one of the standard containers it is better to use `std::map` because it doesn't require elements to have contiguous keys.